# How to copy directory from a public http url to my Server

Tags: php

I have some files in directory and sub directory in an open HTTP site

For Example:

```
http://example.com/directory/file1
http://example.com/directory/file2
http://example.com/directory/sub-directory/file1
http://example.com/directory/sub-directory/file2
http://example.com/directory/sub-directory2/file1
http://example.com/directory/sub-directory2/file2
```

I want to copy the full directory to my server.
I don't have SSH or FTP access to the http://example.com

I have tried transloader script which grabs only one file every time.
I need to copy the full directory exactly as is on the HTTP server to my new server.

Thanks

Comment: You need to have some form of access to a server in order to download files from it.

Comment: You need to have list of those files in directories. Otherwise this is not possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a security issue if you were able to just grab a websites files..?

Answer (score 1):

Use wget or curl:

```
wget -r --no-parent mysite.com
```

Comment: This will only work correctly if it is a simple HTML site. This will not work if it is a php / ruby / python, or any other dynamic application.

Comment: I download the wget but didnt get how to use it :(
do u know any easy script using curl ???

MY hosting is shared hosting .. i do not have access to root :(

Comment: wget is the best answer. It can copy an entire website just as if you were browsing it and keep a local copy. If he has no ssh or ftp access this is his only option. The problem is if there is server side scripting involved, e.g. PHP or Ruby. wget can only retrieve what the web server offers, so of that's HTML and not the PHP source then that's what you get.

Comment: wget is a Linux command line utility. You may need to apt-get install wget or find  Windows binary if you're using that. Not sure if it comes with OSX or not but I know it can be found and used with Macs. Google it.

Comment: there is no server side script running. It is not even a HTML site just some files that are open to public. I need to keep the directory structure intact.

Comment: What code i put in putty to get the folder using wget in my server in a user folder .. not in root

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to do this. You can grab the content of the visual layer/GUI that the site provides to you, but you can not grab any of the "behind the scenes" pages which the site has. You wont be able to get any of the site which is doing the back end processing to create what you see on the front end.

The only way to do do this is if you have access to the directories on the site. By this, I mean when you go to the base directory, such as example.com/test/, it just gives a list of all possible files in that directory. As it stands though, most sites protect against it, therefore unless you have direct access, this is not doable as it would be entirely insecure and would create many headaches for development and privacy.

Comment: I have access to that site .. the file and folder are open for all .. i want to bring then to my other site without downloading

Those are just folder downloaded from torrent ... those are not php or html file.
some jpg some .obj some .zip file inside those folder